# update statement in JTA is committed after timeout happens and rollback status in logs

Tags: spring, sql-update, weblogic, rollback, jta

I am simulating a scenario in weblogic to see how jta works in our project with using spring 4.
Realized that if transaction timeout occurs, my application update statement in this transaction boundary still committed interestingly.

Simalation logic is; get the rowlock with in a seperate app like with TOAD, after transaction time out occurs in application release the lock with commit in TOAD, and expect to be the application side also rollbacks.

what is happening is application is rolling back as per the logs but in DB update is committed.

using weblogic data source, global transaction is disabled. jdbc class is :
**oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver**

config.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/UNICA_TCODS_NONXA"/>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
```

config.java :

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public GetInterestListServiceImpl getInterestListService() {
        return new GetInterestListServiceImpl(dataSource);
    }

}
```

service is like :

```
@Service("GetInterestListService")
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class GetInterestListServiceImpl implements GetInterestListService {

    private static final Logger logger = MnSLogger.getLogger(GetInterestListServiceImpl.class.getName());

    private DataSource dataSource;

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    public GetInterestListServiceImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(template);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    @Override
    public GetInterestListResponse getInterestList(String clientTID,String ffid, String lang) {

        SqlParameterSource namedParametersForGetCampaign = new MapSqlParameterSource("s", lang);
        String sqll = "UPDATE "+ffid+" CSB SET IMAGE_URL_TR=:s";
        System.out.println("sqll = " + sqll); 
        int rowCount = this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sqll, namedParametersForGetCampaign);

        System.out.println("rowCount = " + rowCount);
```

## chronological log is like :

### 5.27.50 -- TOAD

at first, sending an update statement to this table and waiting with out commit to make wait the application intentionally 
sql:
UPDATE lock1 SET IMAGE_URL_TR='www.google.com.tr';

### 5.28.04 -- APP

call the service to start transaction in application end

### 5.28.04 -- APP transaction started.

```
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:04 PM EET> <Debug> <JTA2PC> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1546093684026> <BEA-000000> <java.lang.Exception: DEBUG: Xid=BEA1-001D812805B0(882519654),Status=Active,numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=0,seconds left=-1546093684) wakeUpAfterSeconds(30)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TxDebug.debugStack(TxDebug.java:60)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.wakeUpAfterSeconds(TransactionImpl.java:2015)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.init(TransactionImpl.java:279)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.<init>(TransactionImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.<init>(ServerTransactionImpl.java:196)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.createTransaction(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:2022)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.createTransaction(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:2004)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.internalBegin(TransactionManagerImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.internalBegin(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:360)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.begin(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:335)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.internalBegin(TransactionManagerImpl.java:223)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.begin(TransactionManagerImpl.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doJtaBegin(JtaTransactionManager.java:874)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doBegin(JtaTransactionManager.java:831)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy216.getInterestList(Unknown Source)
    at com.xyz1.crm.unicamobilegateway.controller.UnicaMobileGatewayRestController.getInterestList(UnicaMobileGatewayRestController.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3732)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

### 5.28.04 -- APP

start to try to run the statement.

```
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:04 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCInternal> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093684040> <BEA-000000> < > CE:getCS (10) isCallable = false, sql = UPDATE LOCK1 CSB SET IMAGE_URL_TR=?, resultSetType = -1, resultSetConcurrency = -1, resultSetHoldability = -1, autoGeneratedKeys = -1, columnIndexes = null, columnNames = null>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:04 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCInternal> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093684040> <BEA-000000> <  CE:getCS (25) key = false:UPDATE LOCK1 CSB SET IMAGE_URL_TR=?:-1:-1:-1:-1:null:null>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:04 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCInternal> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093684040> <BEA-000000> <  CE:getCS (30) entry = weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.StatementHolder@6423995f>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:04 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCInternal> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093684040> <BEA-000000> <<  CE:getCS (100.2) entry = weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.StatementHolder@6423995f>
```

### 5.28.38 --APP

since JTA timeout is 30, I can see the transaction rolledback

```
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:38 PM EET>  <JTA2PC> <uatosb01v> <sideAppServer1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1546093718444> <BEA-000000> <java.lang.Exception: DEBUG: Xid=BEA1-001D812805B0(882519654),Status=Active,numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=34,seconds left=-4,activeThread=Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads],SCInfo[xyzdomain+sideAppServer1]=(state=active),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=sideAppServer1+192.168.244.76:10004+xyzdomain+t3+, XAResources={WSATGatewayRM_sideAppServer1_xyzdomain},NonXAResources={})]) wakeUpAfterSeconds(30)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.TxDebug.debugStack(TxDebug.java:60)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.wakeUpAfterSeconds(TransactionImpl.java:2015)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.wakeUp(ServerTransactionImpl.java:1772)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.processTimedOutTransactions(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:1676)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.wakeUp(TransactionManagerImpl.java:1988)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.wakeUp(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:1586)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.WLSTimer.timerExpired(WLSTimer.java:35)
        at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:273)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:38 PM EET>  <JTA2PC> <uatosb01v> <sideAppServer1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1546093718444> <BEA-000000> <java.lang.Exception: DEBUG: Xid=BEA1-001D812805B0(882519654),Status=Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 34 seconds
BEA1-001D812805B0],numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=34,seconds left=30,activeThread=Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads],SCInfo[xyzdomain+sideAppServer1]=(state=active),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=sideAppServer1+192.168.244.76:10004+xyzdomain+t3+, XAResources={WSATGatewayRM_sideAppServer1_xyzdomain},NonXAResources={})]) wakeUpAfterSeconds(30)
>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:38 PM EET>  <JTA2PC> <uatosb01v> <sideAppServer1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1546093718445> <BEA-000000> <java.lang.Exception: DEBUG: Xid=BEA1-001D812805B0(882519654),Status=Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 34 seconds
BEA1-001D812805B0],numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=34,seconds left=30,activeThread=Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads],SCInfo[xyzdomain+sideAppServer1]=(state=active),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=sideAppServer1+192.168.244.76:10004+xyzdomain+t3+, XAResources={WSATGatewayRM_sideAppServer1_xyzdomain},NonXAResources={})]) wakeUpAfterSeconds(10)
>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:48 PM EET>  <JTA2PC> <uatosb01v> <sideAppServer1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1546093728448> <BEA-000000> <wakeUp runing: Xid=BEA1-001D812805B0(882519654),Status=Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 34 seconds
BEA1-001D812805B0],numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=44,seconds left=0,activeThread=Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads],SCInfo[xyzdomain+sideAppServer1]=(state=active),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=sideAppServer1+192.168.244.76:10004+xyzdomain+t3+, XAResources={WSATGatewayRM_sideAppServer1_xyzdomain},NonXAResources={})])>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:48 PM EET>  <JTA2PC> <uatosb01v> <sideAppServer1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1546093728448> <BEA-000000> <java.lang.Exception: DEBUG: Xid=BEA1-001D812805B0(882519654),Status=Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 34 seconds
BEA1-001D812805B0],numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=44,seconds left=0,activeThread=Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads],SCInfo[xyzdomain+sideAppServer1]=(state=active),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=sideAppServer1+192.168.244.76:10004+xyzdomain+t3+, XAResources={WSATGatewayRM_sideAppServer1_xyzdomain},NonXAResources={})]) wakeUpAfterSeconds(30)
>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:48 PM EET>  <JTA2PC> <uatosb01v> <sideAppServer1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1546093728449> <BEA-000000> <BEA1-001D812805B0: null: ServerTransactionImpl.globalRollback()>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:48 PM EET>  <JTA2PC> <uatosb01v> <sideAppServer1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1546093728449> <BEA-000000> <BEA1-001D812805B0: null: TX[BEA1-001D812805B0] active-->rolling back
java.lang.Exception: DEBUG
>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:48 PM EET>  <JTA2PC> <uatosb01v> <sideAppServer1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1546093728449> <BEA-000000> <ServerSCInfo.startRollback: Xid=BEA1-001D812805B0(882519654),Status=Rolling Back. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 34 seconds
BEA1-001D812805B0],numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=44,seconds left=30,activeThread=Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads],SCInfo[xyzdomain+sideAppServer1]=(state=active),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=sideAppServer1+192.168.244.76:10004+xyzdomain+t3+, XAResources={WSATGatewayRM_sideAppServer1_xyzdomain},NonXAResources={})])>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:48 PM EET>  <JTA2PC> <uatosb01v> <sideAppServer1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1546093728449> <BEA-000000> <SC[xyzdomain+sideAppServer1] active-->rolledback
java.lang.Exception: DEBUG
>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:48 PM EET>  <JTA2PC> <uatosb01v> <sideAppServer1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1546093728449> <BEA-000000> <BEA1-001D812805B0: null: TX[BEA1-001D812805B0] rolling back-->rolled back
java.lang.Exception: DEBUG
>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:28:48 PM EET>  <JTA2PC> <uatosb01v> <sideAppServer1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1546093728449> <BEA-000000> <BEA1-001D812805B0: null: releaseLog>
```

### 5:29:31 --APP

commit the transaction in TOAD to move forward the application statement
after releasing the TOAD transaction with commit, app also try to run update. the most interesting this here is below update statements are using transaction "BEA1-001D812805B0" to execute the statement which was recently rolled back.

```
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:29:31 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCSQL> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093771924> <BEA-000000> <[weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@3b] executeUpdate returns 7>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:29:31 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCSQL> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093771925> <BEA-000000> <[weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@3b] getWarnings()>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:29:31 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCSQL> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093771925> <BEA-000000> <[weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@3b] getWarnings returns>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:29:31 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCSQL> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093771927> <BEA-000000> <[weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@3b] close()>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:29:31 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCInternal> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093771927> <BEA-000000> < > CE:retCS (10) entry = weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.StatementHolder@6423995f>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:29:31 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCInternal> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093771927> <BEA-000000> <  CE:retCS (20) key = false:UPDATE LOCK1 CSB SET IMAGE_URL_TR=?:-1:-1:-1:-1:null:null>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:29:31 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCInternal> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093771927> <BEA-000000> < < CE:retCS (100) >
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:29:31 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCSQL> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093771928> <BEA-000000> <[weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@3b] close returns>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:29:31 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCSQL> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093771928> <BEA-000000> <[weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CConnection@3a] close()>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:29:31 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCConn> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093771928> <BEA-000000> <ConnectionEnv.cleanup, jconn=oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@2bc8d34, isXA=false, isJTS=false, jconn.isolationLevel=2, initialIsolationLevel=2, dirtyIsolationLevel=false>
####<Dec 29, 2018 5:29:31 PM EET> <Debug> <JDBCSQL> <uatosb01v> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-001D812805B0> <> <1546093771929> <BEA-000000> <[weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CConnection@3a] close returns>
```

weblogic.out

### 17.28.04

```
2018-12-29 17:28:04,025 DEBUG [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:367) - Creating new transaction with name [com.xyz1.crm.unicamobilegateway.service.impl.GetInterestListServiceImpl.getInterestList]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '',-java.lang.Exception
sqll = UPDATE LOCK1 CSB SET IMAGE_URL_TR=:s
```

### 17:29:31

```
rowCount = 7
2018-12-29 17:29:31,929 DEBUG [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:759) - Initiating transaction commit
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction already rolled back (probably due to a timeout)
        at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1021)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy216.getInterestList(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Because the row is updated by TOAD as you described ?

Comment: no, with toad I am sending update like "UPDATE lock1 SET IMAGE_URL_TR='www.google.com.tr'" but application sends "UPDATE lock1 SET IMAGE_URL_TR='value2'". and in the end, I am expecting toad to be final but although transaction is rollbacked, app update is final as value2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after testing many scenarios and debugging. installing new weblogic 10.3.6 (11g) from scratch, I have found out that weblogic has an issue.

if there is an xa datasource then weblogic can manage this datasource within JTA transaction.
if there is a local datasource, regardless of supporting global transaction with any option or not, weblogic can not manage datasource transaction with in JTA.

there is a weblogic JTA transaction manager issue.